Renew Active Directory claims without logging off
Is there a way to renew Active Directory claims (the ones created with New-ADClaimType cmdlet) without logging off ?
klist purge cannot do such thing, even with a runas command or an explorer process kill after it (whoami /claims displays the same thing after).
Very short kerberos ticket lifetime do not help either.
The goal is this would work in an user context, no admin nor system escalation.
Thanks

What are you trying to achieve?

if a user attribute linked to a claim is changed, I want the user to retrieve the new value in this claim

I am not aware of a way to do that but let me think about it.
